# Calculate point on hypotenuse of right-angled triangle

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Sorry if this is a little basic, but my math is pretty rusty.  I know the point coordinates of the two blue dots.  I also know the distances from the middle blue dot to the edges of the square.  How can I calculate the coordinates of the red dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two right angled triangles in the picture are [similar](http://www.gcseguide.co.uk/similar_triangles.htm). Hence the ratio of the corresponding sides are the same. You can use this to get the remaining coordinates.